# IGlobeGraphicsLayer not updating in separate thread?

Tags: arcobjects, arcglobe

I'm currently using ArcGlobe to create a Polygon on a globe.  Using examples I've found through [arcgis.com](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Sample_Creating_a_toolbar_of_globe_tools/000100000323000000/)  I can now allow the user to click on the globe and create a polygon on the map.  This works as intended and the visualization on the map is seen.

However, I'm now trying to do this in a new thread so I can create a polygon overlay and attempt to return a list of Coordinates from a single point of entry (Since there doesn't seem to be a TrackPolygon function like there is in ArcMap).  When putting this code into it's own thread, the event handlers on the globe still work; however the `GlobeGraphicsLayer.AddElement` is no longer displaying this data on the globe.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ArcObjects are single threaded components and they should communicate between each other only if they are in the same thread. If you want to update ArcObjects from a background worker thread, you need to pass objects as simple types, which in case of complex objects involves serialization.

Th [Writing multithreaded ArcObjects](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Writing_multithreaded_ArcObjects_code/000100000100000000/) document covers these issues and solutions for them in a great detail.